# Понятие о родном языке

Tags: общие-вопросы

В школе постоянно впаривают, что если я документально татарин, то мой родной язык — татарский. Однако я себя не считаю татарином, а на татрском не говорю и язык этот не признаю. В семье у меня тоже никто на нём не говорит.

У понятия *родной язык* есть два определения.

1. Это язык, на котором человек начал говорить.
2. Это язык, который передаётся по национальности.

И как определить, какой у меня родной язык?

Comment: «Язык этот не признаю», — пишете. Это как же?

Comment: Не хочу относиться к этому народу.

Comment: Так мы все к нему как-никак относимся. Чем он вам насолил?

Comment: К татарскому? Вы тоже относитесь?

Comment: Мы в одной стране живём. Как же иначе?

Comment: Но к этносу-то вы вряд ли какое-то отношение имеете.

Comment: Надо поскрести.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ряд ученых, таких, как Крысин, Беликов, опровергают понятие национальный язык как родной, называя его «этнический язык». Они придерживаются мнения, что "родной язык — это язык, который человек усваивает с раннего детства без специального обучения, находясь в соответствующей языковой среде («первый язык»)". Это наиболее распространенная концепция. Так что решать Вам, что принимать за родной язык. Вам же никто не навязывает другой язык.

Лично у меня два родных языка: русский, армянский. Причем последний отвечает сразу двум критериям: эти два языка я освоил с детства, второй критерий - тот, что параллельно армянский по отношению ко мне является национальным. Правда, мыслю на русском, но с армянским проблем нет: на нем свободно говорю, читаю, пишу, перевожу.

Подробно о родном языке можете почитать в Википедии. Там об этом много написано.

Comment: Я в Википедии на эту тему тоже читал. Просто в нашем регионе преподают родные языки (татарский, башкирский и русский родной). Я вхожу в первую группу, и меня пытаются навязать, что это мой родной язык. Этнический язык — это никак не родной язык.

Comment: Тагрикс, покажите им статью в Википедии. Никто не имеет права Вам ничего навязывать.

Comment: Что никто не имеет права навязывать — это понятно. Но статья в Википедии не является высшей инстанцией: энциклопедия как-никак наполняется пользователями...

Comment: Да, вы правы: но они ведь не выдумывают из себя. В конце есть литература,  и, в конце концов, мнение авторитетный ученых, которые там приведены.

Answer (score 2):

> > В школе постоянно выпаривают, что если я документально татарин...

Впаривают!

И в каком же документе у вас написано "татарин"? Даже интересно.
Родной язык – тот, на котором человек начал "мама" говорить. Про "передачу по национальности" я что-то не слышал.

Comment: Да-да, вы не ослышались. Именно впаривают. Иначе это никак не назвать. Я им говорю, что мне не сдался этот ваш татарский, а они пытаются мне доказать, что это мой родной язык. Глупые, короче.

Comment: «Иначе это никак не назвать»? Вы сами и назвали. А ещё «на татрском» не говорите. В Вопросе вообще много смешного. Поправьте, пожалуйста, в части опечаток и стиля; моя правка не прошла из-за вмешательства Марк Из.

Answer (score 2):

Есть конечно концепции, привязывающие родной язык к национальности (хотя большинство учёных считают подобную трактовку надуманной, разделяя родной язык и язык этнический). Но в вашем случае, если вы не самоидентифицируете себя как татарина, то даже этот вариант для вас не подходит.

В других концепциях "родной язык" - это или язык усвоенный в детстве без специального обучения (если таких языков несколько, то родных языков у человека тоже не один), или язык, на котором человек мыслит без дополнительного самоконтроля.

Кстати, в в моей альма матер как-то произошла забавная история. Там преподаёт преподавательница, представитель какого-то вымирающего финно-угорского народа, осталось менее 100 человек. И вот на переписи 2002 г. количество представителей этого народа увеличилось в полтора раза, так как группа, которую она курировала в полном составе решила записаться им. Естественно данные "новофины" в лучшем случае на языке этого народа пару слов знали. Какой он им родной?

Answer (score 2):

Родной язык - тот язык, которым ты свободно владеешь, среди которого ты вырос, который изучался и использовался с самого детства. Например, ты переехал в Англию и изучаешь там английский, учишься на английском, можешь свободно на нём разговаривать, но родной язык всё равно будет русский. Пример № 2: русская семья уехала в Германию (оба говорят на русском), у них родился ребёнок. Воспитывался ребёнок уже на немецком языке, т.е. посещал дет.сад, где говорят по-немецки, в школе учился на немецком. У ребёнка уже родной язык - немецкий, а не русский.

Answer (score 0):

«Как определить, какой у меня родной язык?»
Обычно самому человеку свойственно не задаваться таким вопросом. Но вопрос такой может быть поставлен извне какой-либо анкетой или опросом. Из малого, что известно по вашему небольшому тексту, слишком затруднительно сделать определённый вывод, хотя, если идти от обратного, исключая варианты, ни тот, о котором пытаетесь говорить, ни тот, на котором пытаетесь писать, — вам не родные.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш родной язык тот - на котором вы видите сны. Или на котором будет кричать "мама" в случае опасности.

Ничего навязать вам нельзя в этом плане нельзя. Поэтому улыбаемся и машем. :)

Answer (score 0):

Родной язык - это тот язык, на котором разговаривают или разговаривали ваши родители. Больше не надо ничего придумывать. При этом бывают случаи, когда языки родителей разные. В этом случае считается, что родных языка два.

Answer (score 0):

Родной язык тот, на котором с вами разговаривали в семье.
Это знаете только вы, в документах не записано, только с ваших слов.
Если вы татарин, но родной вам русский, значит так и есть.